# How do I close the tcp client (client.close) with a button?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, client-server, tcpclient

I have a client server application.

if the client has disconnected the server can detect it automatically and remove it from the connected clients list.

I am going to focus on the server now.
I would like to have a Stop Server button. To stop the Listener and Tcp Client Connections.
I can easily stop the listener, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to stop the tcp client ( or issue a Client.Close )

[SERVER]

```
Public Class Server
Dim ClientList As New Hashtable
Dim Listener As TcpListener
Dim ListenerThread As System.Threading.Thread
Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
    ListenerThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Listen)
    ListenerThread.IsBackground = True
    ListenerThread.Start(TextBoxPort.Text)
    ButtonStart.Enabled = False
    ButtonStop.Enabled = True
    ListBox1.Items.Add("[SERVER] Waiting For A Connection...")
End Sub

Sub ClientDisconnected(ByVal Client As ConnectedClient) 
    ClientList.Remove(Client) 'remove the client from the hashtable
    ListBox2.Items.Remove(Client.Name) 'remove it from our listbox
End Sub

Sub Listen(ByVal Port As Integer)
    Try
        Listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port)
        Listener.Start()

        Do
            Dim Client As New ConnectedClient(Listener.AcceptTcpClient)
            AddHandler Client.ReceivedMessage, AddressOf ReceivedMessage
            AddHandler Client.ClientDisconnected, AddressOf ClientDisconnected
        Loop Until False
    Catch

    End Try
End Sub

Dim TotalItemCount As String
Sub ReceivedMessage(ByVal Msg As String, ByVal Client As ConnectedClient)
    Dim Message() As String = Msg.Split("|")
    Select Case Message(0)
        Case "CHAT" 'if it's CHAT
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Client.Name & " Says: " & " " & Message(1))

        Case "SAVETRAN"
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Transaction Number: " + Message(1) + vbCrLf + "Customer Number: " + Message(2))

        Case "TRANDETAIL"
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Barcode: " + Message(1) + vbCrLf + "Quantity: " + Message(2) + vbCrLf + "Price Sold: " + Message(3))
            ProgressBar1.Value += 1
            Label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value

            If Label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
                ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            End If

        Case "ITEMCOUNT"
            ListBox1.Items.Add("SERVER IS EXPECTED TO RECEIVE " + Message(1) + " ITEMS.")
            TotalItemCount = Message(1)
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = TotalItemCount

        Case "LOGIN" 'A client has connected
            ClientList.Add(Client, Client.Name)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(Client.Name)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStop.Click

    Listener.Stop()

    ListBox1.Items.Add("Server Stopped")
    ButtonStop.Enabled = False
    ButtonStart.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Server_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End Sub

End Class
```

In the Server Application there is a class call ConnectedClient

[Connected Client]

```
Public Class ConnectedClient
Public Cli As TcpClient
Private UniqueID As String

Public Property Name

    Get
        Return UniqueID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value)
        UniqueID = Value
    End Set

End Property

Public Sub New(Client As TcpClient)
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim x As String = String.Empty

    For i = 0 To 7
        x &= Chr(r.Next(65, 89))
    Next
    Me.Name = Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Remove(Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().LastIndexOf(":")) & " - " & x

    Cli = Client
    Cli.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Reading, Nothing)
End Sub

Public Event ReceivedMessage(ByVal Message As String, ByVal Client As ConnectedClient)

Public Event ClientDisconnected(ByVal Client As ConnectedClient)

Sub Reading(ByVal AR As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Cli.GetStream)
        Dim Msg As String = Reader.ReadLine()
        RaiseEvent ReceivedMessage(Msg, Me)
        Cli.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Reading, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Try and read again

        Try
            Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Cli.GetStream)
            Dim Msg As String = Reader.ReadLine()
            RaiseEvent ReceivedMessage(Msg, Me)
            Cli.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Reading, Nothing)
        Catch
            RaiseEvent ClientDisconnected(Me)
        End Try
    End Try
End Sub

Sub SendData(ByVal Message As String)
    Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Cli.GetStream)
    Writer.WriteLine(Message)
    Writer.Flush()
End Sub
End Class
```

I was trying somehow to link to the connected client class and get the Client.Close, but I cannot
figure it out.

Comment: The [SERVER] part is the main form thread and has all the buttons on it.

Comment: Just keep a list of references to your ConnectedClient on class level and issue the close for each of them when you are shutting down your server.

Comment: so in the main form, do I dim client as connected client and for each client in the hashtable call client.close. When I tried that I got object reference is not an instance of an object.

Comment: Sounds strange - could you provide more insight in the code you use to access the hashtable to close the clients? Since you're removing ConnectedClients upon the disconnected event you also have to assure that you won't get race conditions when accessing your ConnectedClient Hashtable.